# Reference row in datatabase when all rows have the same data (for update)

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-update, dbf

I have a database of invoices data. Some invoices have multiple items that have the same data. Since database (DBF) has no ID column I don't know how to select one item (row) within invoice to change/`update` data, 'cause when I `UPDATE` 1 item all others rows (that have same data as the one I am changing) are changed too.

```
   Dim query As String = "UPDATE INV SET DATE= ?, NAME=?, " _
                              & "IMD=?, JM=?, WHERE INVOICENUM=? AND PRICE=? AND TAX=?"
```

Can I reference a row from DBF somehow so that other rows with same data are not effected and how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

> ... has no ID column ...

Then how do you identify a record?  The actual UPDATE is structured the same no matter what you do:

```
UPDATE table SET values WHERE identity
```

You have the table, you have the values, you need an identity.  It doesn't necessarily have to be a column *called* `ID`, it doesn't have to be an `IDENTITY` column that auto-increments, it can be any combination of one or more columns which defines one record as uniquely distinct from any other.

It's your data, you tell us.  How do you discern one record from another?

If you *can't* discern one record from another, then your data model is fundamentally broken.  You need to fix it before you can proceed.  If you *can* discern one record from another, then you have your answer.  That `WHERE` clause can be as complex as you want/need it to be, it just has to be able to identify the record.

Comment: I would say it is good practise to put a unique index on the columns forming the natural key.

Comment: @DaniEll: I'd go one further and say the natural key should be the primary key, ideally.  Which comes with a unique index already :)

Comment: There is no identity column of any kind, DBF files are from my old software, and I am not able to get in contact with the guy that programmed that. Software was made in DBASE and is fully functional. I am trying to add some to it w ith VB.NET just to speed some processes. I am putting invoice data in a listview, and selecting one item from it so that I can see data that I am trying to change, problem starts when I have identical items in a invoice and I was hoping to solve that with DBFfile row number as IDENTITY information.

Comment: @Jovica: As I said, it doesn't need to be an `IDENTITY` column.  When you *select* a specific record, how do you *identify* the record you want?  That same identification is what you would use when *updating* that same record.  The history of your database is irrelevant.  You can either uniquely identify records or you can't.  If you can't, then the data is fundamentally broken.  If you're asking "How can I uniquely identify a record when I can't uniquely identify it?" then that question is not only unanswerable, it's downright silly.

Comment: I am selecting data with invoice number, that how I see all items in it through listview. All invoices have unique number, but, as I said earlier, sometimes some of the items are identical within 1 invoice and that when the problem starts.

Comment: @Jovica: Then it sounds like the problem is that the data doesn't have any way to identify records.  The data is, therefore, *fundamentally broken*.  There's no workaround for that.  There's no fix we can advise.  You have records which are naturally different but no way to identify them.  The *only* fix for that is to add some way to identify them.  If you're not allowed to do that then there's no way to add the feature you're trying to add because it *requires* a way to identify records.

Comment: There is no way to change structure of the database file 'cause then software can not read that DBF file. Thank you for your help.